# How to separate the /boot partition in linux?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

My device is only able to boot from SD card or eMMC module, but I don't have eMMC module so I have to boot from the SD card. However, I also have NVMe drive and what I want to do is to make my system boot from SD card, but store everything else (libraries, programs, not only home directory) on the NVMe. Using another drive for /home folder is easy because it only requires from you copying your data to that drive and adding one entry in /etc/fstab, but I can only mount one drive in one directory so I can't for example mount /bin directory on my drive in /bin directory in my filesystem and /home directory on my drive in /home directory in my filesystem. I, of course, am able to make different partitions for each of /bin, /lib, /home, /var... folders but they won't be scalable.

So what I want to do is to have only one partition (and one namespace, because NVMe drives also have namespaces) on my NVMe drive and I want to have /bin, /lib, /home... directories on that drive and want them to mount in /bin, /lib, /home directories in my real filesystem. And this directories that have to be on the SD card (/boot, /etc) I also want to be mounted in corresponding directories.

Comment: You're overthinking this. Make a single root `/` partition and a `/boot` partition. Mount the boot partition into `/boot` on the root partition. Done.

Comment: But I also have to have /etc directory on my SD card because /etc/fstab is in this directory.

Comment: You don't need a separate `/etc` partition. The early filesystem image (initrd/initramfs) stored on `/boot` will contain drivers and information necessary to mount the root filesystem. Once the root filesystem is mounted, `/etc` on it is accessible and fstab is processed.

Comment: Ok. So after making this changes in fstab I will need to run mkinitcpio?

Comment: On Debian derivatives it would be `updateinitramfs -u -k all`. I don't know what other distros use, sorry.

Comment: It's not working. It don't even boot. I have just replaced /dev/mmcblk1p1 content with previous /boot directory content and /dev/nvm0n1 content with / content except boot directory. Then I changed /etc/fstab on /dev/nvm0n1. Finally I mounted /dev/nvm0n1 in /mnt and /dev/mmcblk1p1 in /mnt/boot and ran systemd-nspawn -b -D /mnt and ran update-initramfs -u -k all. Then I rebooted my board and it didn't booted.

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem. I had to modify u-boot configuration file /boot/armbianEnv.txt. If you are using grub you probably need to modify /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: I was going to suggest trying to grab console output using UART, but I'm glad you've figured it out without it. I'll try to formulate an answer based on this comment exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a single root `/` partition and a `/boot` partition. Mount the boot partition into `/boot` on the root partition. That's the usual setup in such situations.

You don't need a separate `/etc` partition. The early filesystem image (initrd/initramfs) stored on `/boot` will contain drivers and information necessary to mount the root filesystem. Once the root filesystem is mounted, `/etc` on it is accessible and fstab is processed.

Remember to update the initramfs (on Debian derivatives it would be `update-initramfs -u -k all`) because it needs to take some info from fstab into account. You may also have to update bootloader configuration. For GRUB that would be `update-grub`, for systemd-boot it's either a `kernelstub` invocation if you're using it or an equivalent operation. On embedded platforms there's probably a uboot configuration file somewhere that needs adjustment. (from OP's own experimentation: `/boot/armbianEnv.txt`)

If this doesn't work and you don't have a display to follow boot messages, I'd suggest using an UART to grab them and see what's wrong.